# What are the types of testing required for a Spring MVC web application to become live?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, testing, e-commerce, integration-testing

### I have developed a spring mvc web application i would like to know what are the types of testing required before the spring mvc web application is live?

I have gone through different types of testing such as unit, integration, regression, functional, security, acceptance and Smoke testing

1. But I would like to know for a  Shopping web application  what are the most necessary or basic types of testing  necessary before web application is live?
2. Is unit and Integration test enough or do I need to incorporate
   regression smoke functional system testing?
3. Is manual testing of entire website enough for
       launching a website ?

Comment: With something like shopping stress tests are going to be useful, too - they are going to show how your application behaves when it's hit with more requests than it can handle, and thus show robustness of your error handling and if the website will go down, or just drop connections it can't handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration Tests,Stress Tests,System Test, Security Tests User Acceptance and Manual Tests should be enough for initial launch on the internet and further as the application grows big we can go for further types of testing such as component testing,functional testing and many others for successful and robust e commerce web application deployment.But for initial startups manual testing should be given more focus and also Test Driven Development (TDD) can be followed .In TDD As the developer codes he himself writes the test cases this is to predict the results of the application but for a startup manual testing , System and Security testing must be given priority.